# using observablecollection and cxml in 1 pivotviewer

Tags: silverlight-5.0, cxml-collectionxml

I am new to  `pivotviewer` and also to `silverlight`. I have created a `observablecollection` which has
the properties

```
public string StaffName { get; set; }
   public string Location {get;set;}
```

using a method `BuildCollection()` I bind it to `mainpage.xaml` in the following manner:

```
<pivot:PivotViewer x:Name="pViewer">
  <pivot:PivotViewer.ItemTemplates>
    <pivot:PivotViewerItemTemplate MaxWidth="300">
      <Border Width="300" Height="300" 

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StaffName}" 
                        FontSize="90"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Foreground="White"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Border>
    </pivot:PivotViewerItemTemplate>
  </pivot:PivotViewer.ItemTemplates>
</pivot:PivotViewer>
```

Now I want to bind the CXML file `cities.cxml` which resides in the `clientbin` which has the images and also the property called Location.  I want to create a link between the collection and the cxml so that when i  deepzoom the collection which shows the staffname it should fade into the image of the city which is in the cxml collection. for ex Location is london in observable collection I should be deepzoom it to the image of london from the cxml file.  Can anyone help in achieving this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First the observable collection was bound.  Here I added a property called `img` in the observable collection which represents the image index in the xml file
2. I bound the xml file to another template and in the `subimagehost` I bound the `img` index therefore on deepzooming the observable collection I got the image also

   ```
   <pivot:PivotViewerItemTemplate>
               <Grid Width="800" Height="800" Background="LightGray"  MaxWidth="800">

                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Rectangle Fill="{Binding StaffName,  Converter={StaticResource xconv}}"/>
                   <pivot:PivotViewerMultiScaleSubImageHost CollectionSource="http://localhost:65535/ClientBin/Map_files/wr5bbwrn.dre.xml" ImageId="{Binding  img}" >


                   </pivot:PivotViewerMultiScaleSubImageHost>

                                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vehicle}"
                       FontSize="40"
                       Margin="150,200,150,150"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
               </Grid>
           </pivot:PivotViewerItemTemplate>
   ```